# Query with MAX DATE and GROUP BY COLUMNS doesn't use Indexes

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, group-by, query-optimization

I have `posts` table consisting of 100K rows having the below schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `message` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `status` TINYINT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL,
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id),
    INDEX `created_at` (`created_at`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I am trying to execute the below query for fetching the user_id's with last created date grouped by user and post status:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `status`, max(`created_at`) 
FROM `posts`
GROUP BY `user_id`, `status`;
```

This select query is taking a lot of time and when i do explain on the select query, It's not using any indexes at all. How can i rewrite the query in order to use indexes and make it faster.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for taking care to write your question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to satisfy your query completely from this covering index.

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX id_status_date (user_id, status, created_at DESC);
```

That should be pretty fast.

MySQL still has to scan all 100K rows of your index. There's no magic that makes summarizing an entire large table instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index using the `group by` columns: `INDEX (user_id, status)`

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(user_id, status, created_at)
```

The optimizer will hop through the table finding each "MAX".  The number or rows touched will be equal to the number of rows in the output.

Also, remove this so the Optmizer won't use it by mistake:

```
INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`)
```